# Template engin for e-mails

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I use opentbs for document templates (writer and ms word). Now I want to use opentbs also for write e-mails. So that I can read an .msg file prepared from the office and than add senders, customer names, ... so that I have an individual e-mail.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You simply need to use the TinyButStrong Template Engine without the OpenTBS extension.

[See the emailing example](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=email)